# Enable multiple hidden fields with checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, smarty

I have a nested foreach loop and I want to activate the hidden inputs only when the checkbox is activated.  I almost have it, the proper inputs activate if I click the checkbox but fail to deactivate if I uncheck.

Here is the loop;

```
{foreach $order as $pickup}
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="input_control" value="{$pickup.order_number}"/>
ORDER #{$pickup.order_number} Sold to {$pickup.first_name} {$pickup.last_name} (${$pickup.order_total|string_format:"%.2f"})
<ul> {foreach $order_products as $products}{if $products.order_number == $pickup.order_number}
<li><input type="hidden" name="index_val[]" class="{$products.order_number}" disabled/>{$products.item_name} x's{$products.quant}</li>
{/if}{/foreach}
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                             </ul>{/foreach}
```

And  here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input_control').click(function(){
        if($('input[class='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == false){
            $('input[class='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('input[class='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);    
        }
    });
});
```

For testing purposes I turned the hiddens to type=text. Still a beginner at Javascript so any help debugging would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input_control').click(function(){
        if(!$('input.'+ $(this).attr('value')).prop('disabled')){
            $('input.'+ $(this).attr('value')).prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $('input.'+ $(this).attr('value')).prop('disabled', false);    
        }
    });
});
```

1. You can use class selector for simplifying code.
2. Use `.prop()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I can understand whats going on -- win win

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input_control').click(function () {
        $('input.' + this.value).prop('disabled', !this.checked)
    });
});
```

- Use class selector to get the input element
- use .prop() to set the disabled state
- use the checked state of the checkbox to set the disabled state(if the checkbox is checked then the input field is enabled)